# отрисовка дуги в си шарп

Tags: c#

[image: Задание]
Вот есть такое задание на C#. Саму фигуру состоящую из окружностей и прямых я нарисовал. Необходимо обвести её жирной линией. Точки пересечения окружностей планирую находить вот по этому [алгоритму](http://www.litunovskiy.com/gamedev/intersection_of_two_circles/)
Надо найти точки пересечения прямых и окружностей, и потом я так думаю надо отрисовывать дугами, либо каким то образом делать массив точек и рисовать точками. Как лучше сделать? Если рисовать дугами, как провести дугу через 2 крайние точки и зная радиус окружности по границе которой пройдёт дуга.

Comment: если привести часть кода, который надо обработать, то остальным будет проще вам помочь

Comment: @lexxl в том то и дело что кода по сути еще нет. Я только общую фигуру нарисовал тремя окружностями и тремя прямыми

Comment: В чем рисуете то? Если это допускает задание, можно воспользоваться встроенным комбинированием примитивов и получить результат наименьшими затратами.

Comment: @AlexKrass рисую в paintbox в си шарп

Comment: Ну, winforms хоть или wpf?

Comment: @VladD winforms

Answer (score 1):

Тут тьма вариантов, в зависимости от вашего желания разбираться с тригонометрией. Мне вот влом будет для такого задания считать углы и дуги. Мне, например, самым простым кажется такой вариант: абсолютно все точки, которые есть на рисунке (точки прямых и окружностей) затолкать в массив и рисовать отдельно (там ведь должна быть функция "нарисовать жирную точку"). Далее, делаем проверку: если точка находится строго внутри треугольника или любой окружности - делаем её обычной жирности, если нет, то делаем жирной. Сами точки прямых и окружностей можно найти с помощью [алгоритма Брезенхэма](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%B0). Не обязательно брать из википедии, полно готовых реализаций в сети. Понятно, что предложенный метод неэффективен, но суть подобных тупых задач - сдать задачу. Будь задача интересней, я бы рассчитал углы и честно нарисовал бы дуги.

Comment: Боюсь просто что препод не оценит такого подхода, но спасибо за подсказку

Comment: В таком случае, не вижу трудности рассчитать точки, углы и рисовать дуги с помощью метода типа DrawArc. Немножко математики - и всё готово. Или Вы хотите, чтобы Вам помогли рассчитать? Ещё вариант: нарисовать все контуры жирным, а сами фигуры (круги и треугольник) сделать как бы полупрозрачными и белыми внутри (скажем, 50% прозрачности). Они своей полупрозрачностью как бы сделают не такой жирной ту часть точек, что попадёт строго к ним внутрь. Конечно, если полурозрачность существует в функциях языка.

Comment: вот я и спрашиваю как вычислить дуги

Comment: Ну, тут задачи за Вас не решают. Могу сказать идею. Точки на самой окружности Вы найти можете (сами написали). Теперь переносим систему отсчёта в центр круга (вычитаем из координат точки координаты центра круга). Теперь, пусть точка на дуге имеет координаты (X,Y). Тангенс угла определяется через отношение Y/X (тут нужно рассмотреть ещё номер четверти, в которых лежат точки и случай X=0). Зная тангенс, знаете угол первой точки (через арктангенс) по отношению к оси OX. Также со второй точкой. Затем функция рисования дуги должна получить на вход два угла - от какого до какого ей рисовать.